# Generic method to catch error return using expect script (shell)

Tags: shell, expect

I have a expect script which interacts with modem on specific IP and port number. I want to report error to the user if spawn telnet   timeouts or not able to connect for some reason. In short, I want to print a error message and exit if the command fails rather than the script continuing further.

```
set -e doesn't work on expect script.
```

Your advise will help me fix this issue. thanks.

Would like to re-emphasis that I am using expect script and not bash/sh.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
try {
    spawn telnet $HOSTIP $HOSTPORT
} on error {
    exit 1
}
....
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `expect` for `timeout` and `eof` to handle your situation.

```
spawn telnet $HOSTIP $HOSTPORT
# To control the timeout value, update this variable
set timeout 60; # 1 min.
expect {
    timeout {puts "Time-out happened;exit 1}
    eof {puts "EOF occured";exit 1} 
    "required-pattern" {puts "The modem is accessible"; exit 0}
}
```

Replace the `"required pattern"` string with your whatsoever pattern to confirm the accessibility of the devices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Am not sure of the required-pattern as I dont get any prompt or nothing gets printed on STDOUT after the session is established. In that case, if i ignore the line "required-pattern" {puts "......"; exit 0}, the scripts exits with timeout even if its connected to modem. Kindly help me out. thanks.

Comment: To make control expect anything other than timeout or eof, i gave "*"; and the script continued. Thank you for your solution.!